# Transformation rule of a partial derivative

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

We know the following transformation rule:

$$ \partial'_b = \frac{\partial}{\partial x'^b} = \frac{\partial x^c}{\partial x'^b} \, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^c} = \frac{\partial x^c}{\partial x'^b} \, \partial_c. $$

Here $\partial_c$ is covariant tensor of rank $1$.

But what is the corresponding transformation rule for

$$ \partial^m :=g^{mn}\partial_n?$$

How can we derive the transformation rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule is
\begin{align}
  \partial'^a = \frac{\partial x'^a}{\partial x^c}\partial^c 
\end{align}
and is proven as follows:
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_a'} 
&= g'^{ab}\frac{\partial}{\partial x'^b} \\
&= \frac{\partial x'^a}{\partial x^c}\frac{\partial x'^b}{\partial x^d} g^{cd}\frac{\partial x^e}{\partial x'^b}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^e} \\
&= \frac{\partial x'^a}{\partial x^c}\delta^e_d g^{cd}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^e}\\
&= \frac{\partial x'^a}{\partial x^c} g^{ce}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^e}\\
&= \frac{\partial x'^a}{\partial x^c}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_c}
\end{align}
where $g^{ab}$ are the components of the inverse metric and transform as a rank $\binom{2}{0}$ tensor field.

Comment: We get $$ \partial'_b = \frac{\partial}{\partial x'^b} = \frac{\partial x^c}{\partial x'^b} \, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^c} = \frac{\partial x^c}{\partial x'^b} \, \partial_c. $$ using chain rule.

Can we get the transformation rule for $\partial^a$ without using metric tensor? Are there any other way?

Comment: Since $\partial^a$ is *defined* by raising the index on $\partial_a$ using the inverse metric, I don't see a way to avoid involving the metric.

Comment: @Ome Sure thing.