Transformation to replace a Material derivative with a spatial derivative
In the technical paper referenced below, Gringarten et al. claim that the transient energy transport equation  in a planar conduit (Eq. 1 in their paper)
$$
\rho c  \Bigg[ \frac{\partial T(z,t)}{\partial t}+v\frac{\partial T(z,t)}{\partial z}\Bigg]=Q(t)
$$
can be reduced with the transformation $ t^\prime=t-(z/v)$ to Eq (A1) in their appendix
$$
\rho c v  \frac{\partial T(z,t^\prime)}{\partial z}=Q(t^\prime)
$$
Despite attempting all sorts of manipulations with the chain rule, I simply cannot derive their Eq. (A1) - how does the material derivative get replaced entirely with a spatial derivative in terms of the transformed time?!
Any pointers on how they did this would be deeply appreciated. Thanks.
Gringarten, A. C., Witherspoon, P. A., and Ohnishi, Y., 1975, “Theory of Heat Extraction from Fractured Hot Dry Rock”, Journal of Geophysical Research, Vol 80, N0. 8, 1975.
I've included a snapshot of the relevant equations from their paper below:


Use the transformation rule for partial derivatives:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial {x^\prime}^\mu}=\sum_\nu\left(\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial {x^\prime}^\mu}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}$
for $\mu,,\nu\in{0,1}$.

See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28912/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79836/25301, probably others


In the technical paper referenced below, Gringarten et al. claim...
$$
\rho c  \Bigg[ \frac{\partial T(z,t)}{\partial t}+v\frac{\partial T(z,t)}{\partial z}\Bigg]=Q(t)
$$
can be reduced with the transformation $ t^\prime=t-(z/v)$ to Eq (A1) in their appendix
$$
\rho c v  \frac{\partial T(z,t^\prime)}{\partial z}=Q(t^\prime)
$$
Despite attempting all sorts of manipulations with the chain rule, I simply cannot derive their Eq. (A1) - how does the material derivative get replaced entirely with a spatial derivative in terms of the transformed time?!

The authors are perpetrating a horrible abuse of notation by letting the symbol $T$ stand for two different functions. This is confusing, but nontheless quite common in physics.
What the authors mean is that there is some other scalar function $\tilde T$ that is rather simply related to $T$, by the relationship:
$$
\tilde T(z,t') = T(z, t(t')) = T(z,t'+\frac{z}{v})\;,
$$
where we used
$$
t = t' + \frac{z}{v}
$$
since
$$
t' = t - \frac{z}{v}\;.
$$
From here it is just the chain rule:
$$
\frac{\partial \tilde T}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial T}{\partial z}+\frac{1}{v}\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}
$$
So then:
$$
\rho c v 
\frac{\partial \tilde T}{\partial z} 
= \rho c (v\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial T}{\partial t})
$$

Thanks! This makes sense! Should the second equality in your first equation above be $=T(z,t^\prime+\frac{z}{v})$ ?

Is the chain rule supposed to applied as
$\frac{\partial \bar{T}}{\partial z} =\frac{\partial T}{\partial z} +\frac{\partial t}{\partial z} \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$ ? This sounds counter-intuitive to me, because $z$ and $t$ are two independent variables. Is it however due to the fact that $z$ and $t$ are linked through $t^\prime$ ?

@SharatVChandrasekhar Yes, that was a typo. It has been fixed now.

@SharatVChandrasekhar Regarding your second question, yes. The authors effectively treat $z$ and $t'$ as independent in $\tilde T(z,t')$, but treat $z$ and $t$ as independent in $T(z,t)$. Basically $\partial/\partial z$ always means partial differentiation wrt the first argument (for either $T$ or $\tilde T$). But differentiation wrt to the second argument is denoted as $\partial/\partial t'$ for $\tilde T$ and differentiation wrt the second argument is denoted as $\partial/\partial t$ for $T$.
